# Relationships in Knockout,js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm just getting my feet of the ground with knockout and before I munge together some abomination of code I was wondering If anyone could help with the following:

I have a group array

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name" : "tekken characters",
  "members": [1, 3]
}, //etc]
```

and a members array

```
[{ "id": 1, "name": "nina williams" }, {"id": 2, "name": "super mario"}, {"id": 3, "yoshi mitsu"}]
```

Both are returned via seperate API calls.  There is a parent child (one to many) relationship.  What is the best pattern to apply to this sort of data using Knockout.js?

Though I do use each array individually, for example I have a list of all my groups and a list of all my members, I also want a list of groupMembers.  Notice not all members belong to each group.  Is this a computed value where I map ids to each other or, what's the best approach?  The calls are all ajax based so timing is important.

If anyone has done this, or knows of good resources to handle these sorts of relationship/data structures it'd be useful to share them.

Comment: Are you making both API calls at the same time, and are not sure which one is returned first?

Comment: Yeah both calls are made at the same time. And I can't be certain which is returned first.  the lists are both constant once loaded.  But group members changes as the user clicks between groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then the KO view model might look something like this:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;     
    self.groups = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.members = ko.observableArray([]);     

    self.addToGroups = function(data) {
        // Add a new group/groups to view model (e.g. with AJAX)
    };
    self.addToMembers = function(data) {
        // Add a new member/members to view model
    };
    self.membersInGroups = ko.computed(function() {
        // Do some logic like getting members in groups
    }, this);
}
```

Then I would use view models for both groups and members:

```
function groupViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.members = ko.observableArray(data.members);    
}

function memberViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}
```

Check out fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DcaP2/

Comment: When the member ID changes, it does not update the group member IDs. Then what is the meaning of using KO ?